# sql grouping grades

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table for subjects as follows:

```
id  Subject Grade   Ext
100 Math    6       +
100 Science 4       -
100 Hist    3       
100 Geo     2       +
100 CompSi  1
```

I am expecting output per student in a class(id = 100) as follows:

```
Grade   Ext StudentGrade
6       +       1
6               0
6       -       0
5       +       0
5               0
5       -       0
4       +       0
4               0
4       -       1
3       +       0
3               1
3       -       0
2       +       1
2               0
2       -       0
1       +       0
1               1
1       -       0
```

I would want this done on oracle/sql rather than UI. Any inputs please.

Comment: It's not clear what is your output , please provide more information using sample data and explain it in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate rows first, before join them with your table like below. I use the with clause here to generate the 18 rows in your sample.

```sql
with rws (grade, ext) as (
select ceil(level/3), decode(mod(level, 3), 0, '+', 1, '-', null)
from dual 
connect by level <= 3 * 6
)
select r.grade, r.ext, nvl2(t.Ext, 1, 0) studentGrade 
from rws r
left join your_table t
on t.Grade = r.Grade and decode(t.Ext, r.Ext, 1, 0) = 1
order by 1 desc, decode(r.ext, null, 2, '-', 3, '+', 1)
```

Comment: If you are doing it this way, it would be simpler to generate the 18 levels, left-outer-join the result to the input data (on conditions using `ceil(level/3)` and `mod(level,3)` directly in the join condition), group by level, order by level desc, and define the "grade" and "extenstion" expressions in the `select` clause. The code will likely look cleaner that way.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. In the WITH clause I generate two small "helper" tables (really, inline views) for grades from 1 to 6 and for "extensions" of +, null and -. In the "extensions" view I also create an "ordering" column to use in ordering the final output (if you are wondering why I included that).

Also in the WITH clause I included sample data - you will have to remove that and instead use your actual table name in the main query.

The idea is to cross-join "grades" and "extensions", and left-outer-join the result to your input data. Count the grades from the input data, grouped by grade and extension, and after filtering the desired id. The `decode` thing in the join condition is needed because for extension we want to treat `null` as equal to `null` - something that `decode` does nicely.

```
with
  sample_inputs (id, subject, grade, ext) as (
    select 100, 'Math'   , 6, '+'  from dual union all
    select 100, 'Science', 4, '-'  from dual union all
    select 100, 'Hist'   , 3, null from dual union all
    select 100, 'Geo'    , 2, '+'  from dual union all
    select 100, 'CompSi' , 1, null from dual
  )
, g (grade) as (select level from dual connect by level <= 6)
, e (ord, ext) as (
    select 1, '+'  from dual union all
    select 2, null from dual union all
    select 3, '-'  from dual
  )
select g.grade, e.ext, count(t.grade) as studentgrade
from   g cross join e left outer join sample_inputs t
          on  t.grade = g.grade and decode(t.ext, e.ext, 0) = 0
          and t.id = 100  -- change this as needed!
group  by g.grade, e.ext, e.ord
order  by g.grade desc, e.ord
;
```

OUTPUT:

```
GRADE EXT STUDENTGRADE
----- --- ------------
    6 +              1
    6                0
    6 -              0
    5 +              0
    5                0
    5 -              0
    4 +              0
    4                0
    4 -              1
    3 +              0
    3                1
    3 -              0
    2 +              1
    2                0
    2 -              0
    1 +              0
    1                1
    1 -              0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want sparse data to be filled in as part of joining students and subjects.

Since Oracle 10g the correct way to do this has been with a "partition outer join".

The documentation has examples.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6